# How to declare a variable depending on user input in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, variables, declaration

I want to create a program where the user will input a number on a text box and the program will create a number of variables depending on the number when he/she pressed the submit button. (Windows Forms)

For example, user will input 3 on text box and when he/she pressed the submit button the program will create a variable labeled length1,length2,length3 as int inside the program to be use for other purposes later.

Comment: Since `Windows Forms` is mentioned, I presume the language used is `vb.net`? If so, `vb6` is a different, though similar, language where the solution would be different.  Please edit the tags to reflect the language actually being used.

Comment: You can't really create variables like that.  The simplest solution would be to use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0), such as `Dictionary(Of String, Int)`.   The variable name "length1", "length2", etc. would be the KEY and the Int associated with the variable name would be the VALUE.  Store the Dictionary at Form/Class level so it can be accessed from everywhere.  If you need it to be global to your whole program then declare it as Public in a Module.

Comment: Why not just create an array like so: `Dim lengths%(CInt(TextBox1.Text))`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a list like this:

```
Private Numbers As New List(Of Number)

Private Class Number
       Public Name As String
       Public Value As Integer
End Class
```

Next create a procedure that will add integers and a name to the list:

```
Private Sub AddNumbers()
       If IsNumeric(textbox1.Text) = false Then
           Exit Sub
       End If
       For i = 1 to Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.Text)
           Numbers.Add(New Number With {.Name = "length" & i, .Value = 0})
       Next
End Sub
```

I assume that that the textbox is called textbox1. Then you can call the AddNumbers sub from the submit button like this:

```
AddNumbers()
```

You can retrieve a number from the list like this:

```
Numbers(0).Value
```

Comment: The for loop should loop through `Textbox1.Text`, not `Textbox1.Text.Length`. Though that does assume Textbox1 will contain only numeric characters, if there are non-numerics then an exception will likely be thrown with the existing code. Although if `Option Strict` is on (which it should be) then a compile error will result - `Textbox1.Text` needs to be converted to a numeric (integer?) in that case.

Comment: vb.net has several methods like `CInt`, `CDec`, etc. that are optimized for vb.net.

Comment: You wouldn't need a class if you used a Dictionary(Of String, Integer).

Comment: In .net we have `TryParse` methods that replace the old vb6 `IsNumeric`

Answer (score 0):

Using List to create a number of Integer variables.

```
Public length As List(Of Integer)
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i = 1 To Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text)
        length.Add(0)
    Next
End Sub
```

Then you can get the variable by `length(0)`.

Don't forget to limit the TextBox to only enter numbers and backspace.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = Chr(8) Then
        e.Handled = False
    Else
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How about a `TryParse` when the user is done entering instead of checking each keystroke?